# Is there a way to make the game NOT ask me about changing the difficulty after multiple deaths?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I'm playing Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning on the Hard difficulty setting because I would like to get all of the achievements on one playthrough.  In some areas I tend to die quite a bit and I've noticed that after a certain number of deaths in the same area the game will ask if I want to change to a lower difficulty.  I am paranoid that at some point I will be spamming the 'A' button to get going again and accidentally bump down my difficulty, come to the end of the game and come to find that I missed the achievement for beating the game on Hard.

Is there a way to make the game not tempt me into playing on an easier difficulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just flipped through all of the settings on PC and several forums and I didn't see anything of the sort. You would think after you refused the offer X amount of times they would just stop asking. I have only got it once on my game, but I am playing on normal. I can't confirm this, but I would think that even if you hit 'A' they probably ask you if you are sure that it what you want to do.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure they don't. Either that or I was spamming the reload-button faster than I thought when I accidentally changed my difficulty yesterday.

Comment: I guess worst case scenario, save often and if you bump it down by accident reload from a previous save. This might be a tad bit easier on PC though.